# How to add var information from include file in Google Maps V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I was wondering if you could do includes like you can with php in java for Google Maps. I have this right now currently which assigns the colors for my polygons.

```
var lineColor = {
"Tornado Warning":                   "#FF0000",
"Severe Thunderstorm Warning":       "#FFFF33",
"Flash Flood Warning":               "#00FF00",
};
```

Well that list is going to get very very long so instead of having a long list in the main code where it will be really long and cluttering things. I want to put that in a separate file and call that file. I have this currently.

```
// Assign colors to alerts
    var lineColor = 'xml/alertColors.html';
```

Then I have created a html file with this in it.

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">


{
"Tornado Warning":                   "#FF0000",
"Severe Thunderstorm Warning":       "#FFFF33",
"Flash Flood Warning":               "#00FF00",
"Flood Advisory":                    "#00FF7F",
"Special Weather Statement":         "#00FFFF",
};

</script>
</html>
```

It doesn't work so is what I am trying to do even possible or am I doing something wrong? I am not use to working with JavaScript so I don't know if it works the same as php includes.

-Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. All I had to do was put that entire var lineColors with it's array in its own .js file like I had done and call it like above the script like I was doing.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="line_color.js"></script>`

I didn't have to add any other kind of call the original file as that included it already so when it needed to be referenced in the script it pulled the array in its entirety from the included file. So now I have nice neat code without the long data array.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a file named `line_color.js` (or anything you like with `.js`) and put those code in it like

```
var lineColor = {
    "Tornado Warning": "#FF0000",
    "Severe Thunderstorm Warning": "#FFFF33",
    "Flash Flood Warning": "#00FF00" // don't use comma after last entry
};
```

In your main `HTML` file's `<head>` section just add a link to this file like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="line_color.js"></script>
```

So, now you can use those settings/variable like

```
<script>
    alert(lineColor['Tornado Warning']); // #FF0000
</script>
```

Comment: If I did it like alert(lineColor['Tornado Warning']); // #FF0000 that would defeat the purpose because it would be redundant wouldn't it?

Comment: What does that mean, This is only an example to use it.

Comment: I have a google map that parses data from an XML file and depending on the element event in the XML file which is about 50 events it will assign var lineColor to the event element from the XML to assign the polygon a color. This is dynamic content so it's ever changing. While your example works for static content I would have to add alert(lineColor['Tornado Warning']); // #FF0000 and there after for every event possible making it redundant. I am trying to prevent having a long list of code and just putting the var line color in a single file then call that file in place of the array as needed.

Comment: Ok maybe this will help describe it better. Here is a example map where the code is. http://www.mesquiteweather.net/googlemap_poly.html if you view source you will see at the top var lineColor with an array of titles and colors. That is called by data from the XML file depending on the element event. Here is a file with just the array. http://www.mesquiteweather.net/xml/alertColors.js I want to call that file where var lineColor is to replace the array so I don't have so much code in the script. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Figured it out. All I have to do was put that var with it's array in its own .js file and call it like so <script type="text/javascript" src="line_color.js"></script> I didn't have to add any other kind of call the original file.